# How to exit the coverage run process if one of the tests is taking more than x sec in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, coverage.py

I am using [coverage in python](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.1.1/) to run unit tests.

I am using the below command for this ->

```
coverage run --source . -m pytest --junitxml=unit_test_results.xml --disable-pytest-warnings --ignore=<some_file_path>
```

The issue I am facing with this is some UTs(unit tests) are taking longer time to get executed due to mocking issue.

Hence I want to exit the `coverage run` process when any test takes more than `x` unit time.

I have been searching this for a long time but not able to find a solution.

Could anyone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: I think there is a `--timeout` option. for more info check this out https://pypi.org/project/pytest-timeout/

Comment: Hi @VishalSingh, I checked it. It is only showing which tests are taking longer time (say 
>x sec) to get executed. What I wanted is, the execution of coverage should exit/stop right away, if I see any one test is taking >x unit time.